# Precompile Python Script and Include it in another Python Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyc

I have been conducting a learning algorithm using Decision Tree Classifier in Python.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train, train_label)
predicted_label = clf.predict(test)
```

The Decision Tree Classifier accepts training labels from a large text file.
I want to run the program without performing again the training process. How will I do it in Python? How will I include a precompiled learning model and used it for testing in another program? Is precompiled python files does have anything to do with it?

Comment: try pickle to save your model.

Comment: Thank you @MohamedThasinah . Put your comment in the answer section so that I can mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Added to the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After training your model, you could save your model for future use for avoiding the process of training.

```
import pickle
model.fit(X,y)
saved_model = pickle.dump(model,open('saved_model.sav', 'wb'))#save your model
.
.
.

model = pickle.loads(open('saved_model.sav', 'rb'))#get your model from saved model file
model.predict(X[0:1])#use without training
```